# division in df and visualizing the frequency, python

Tags: python, dataframe, frequency, division

I am new to python and got stuck here.

this is what I have, but my dataframe is way bigger:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[657776.0], [637777.0], [627747.0]]
example = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Age'])
example
```

What I tried to do is to:

1. to convert each number to normal age by division, so that 657776.0 become 65, 637777.0 become 63 and etc.
2. then I tried to get some table that will say, the most of people in this dataframe are this age (for example 63).

I tried to apply built-in function but did not succeed, could you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: did you try `example['Age']//10000`?

Comment: Thank you! It works!!! Could I apply age.value_counts() in this case for the correct result (if I want to know what age is the most frequent)?